# vim regex not need \ to escape

Tags: vim, regular-expression

In Vim is there an option to write regexs in the same style as Awk for example
`/sp\{0,\}/`  
 Would be

`/sp{0,}/`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Preceding your pattern with `\v` will make the pattern “magic”, and symbols like `{` and `[` have an interpreted meaning (and literals need to be escaped).

So `/\vsp{1,}` would find what you wanted (I just tested it).

You can make this a sort of default by remapping `/` to `/\v` with the following lines in your vimrc:

```
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
```

See [`:help pattern`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) for more.

Answer (score 0):

`/sp\{0,}`

Of course for `{0,}`, you would be better off using `*`: `/sp*` would (same as the above) find an 's' followed by zero or more p's.  Note that zero or more is *always* true, so there's no reason for it in this particular expression.

Comment: This was all good info and very useful. Is there a way to turn of the escaping of special characters in vim?

Comment: I see what you mean now.  I seriously doubt it, that would almost certainly require a different parser developed in parallel, and I doubt it would be a feature with enough demand to justify that extra implementation and maintenance.

Answer (score -1):

Vim does not have an option to emulate awk-style regular expressions, no. There are a lot of dialects of regex, and unfortunately there are always these little dialectical differences to keep track of when going from one tool to another.